# iPhone SDK: Getting Contact's Name from the Phone Number

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Does anyone know if there is a preferred method to find a contact's name in the Address book using their phone number as the key?

It seems that this should be a standard function since it is done in several places by the phone, such as in Recent Calls, Voice Mail list, Incoming Call ID, etc.

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to do it is to enumerate through all the contacts, enumerate through each contacts phone numbers, and check each one until you find a hit. If you think there should be a built in way to query by phone number directly you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a feature request.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that.   However I must say I am surprised that will all of the various phone functions (Recent Calls, Caller ID etc) that perform this same search that it is that manual.

Perhaps Apple has some proprietary function for it.